# telegram bot: continue a conversation in private

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to create a bot that can be started from a chat group but continue the conversation privately.
My ConversationHandler is simple:

```
ConversationHandler(
  entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start)],

  states={
     ONE: [MessageHandler(Filters.text, get_type)],
     TWO: [MessageHandler(Filters.text, get_category)]
  },

  fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)],
  allow_reentry=True
)
```

my first message (from start) it's sent to the private chat

```
update.message.from_user.id
```

And it works, since the conversation was started from the user.
The problem is that the bot does not recognize anything typed in the private chat as part of the conversation. If I set a echo msghandler, it uses it. If I don't have that, nothing happens.

How should I do that? Everything works fine if I start the conversation privately. Last resort I send a private message to ask the user to /start the conversation.

Comment: try per_chat=False?

Comment: @jeffffc yes, thanks. if you write it as an answer I will accept it.